# how to invoke variable values into Serverless template from gitlab variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a serverless template which is used to provision Lambda and API Gateway. I have hard coded vpc details in template as of now, but I want to invoke variables values from gitlab variables, instead of hard-code values.

I need to get variable values from gitlab variables for SG1, Subnet_A and Subnet_B. Please suggest how can I invoke values?

########### serverless.template ##########

```
{

  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",

  "Description": "testing",

  "Parameters": {},

  "Conditions": {},

  "provider": "aws"

    "environment":

      "Role": "${env:role}"


  "Resources": {

    "AspNetCoreFunction": {

      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",

      "Properties": {

        "Handler": 

              "<Handler_Value>",

        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",

        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": "${Role}",
        "Policies": null,
        "VpcConfig": {
          "SecurityGroupIds": ["$SG1"],
          "SubnetIds": [
            "${Subnet_A}",
            "${Subnet_B}"
          ]
        },
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          },
          "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },


  "Outputs": {

    "ApiURL": {

      "Description": "testing",

      "Value": {

        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/dev/"

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace any value in your `serverless.yml` enclosed by `${env:..}` brackets with the environment variable value,

in the same way you are doing it in `"Role": "${env:role}"`,

- you can replace: `"SecurityGroupIds": ["$SG1"]`
- by `"SecurityGroupIds": ["${env:SG1}"]`

I recommend you to have `unresolvedVariablesNotificationMode` set to `'error'`, to let you know when there's a missing environment variable,

Serverless Framework Guide to Variables: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Comment: Hi. I have changed as you suggested, but still having issues.  I have kept environment varisbles like below, and used these environment variables under resources.                                                                                                         "provider": "aws"
    "environment":
      "Role": "${env:role}"
      "DEV_SG1" "${env:DEV_SG1}"
      "Subnet_A" "${env:Dev_Subnet_A}"
      "Subnet_B" "${env:Dev_Subnet_B}"

Comment: "Resources"                                                                                                              
        "Role": "${env:Role}",
        "Policies": null,
        "VpcConfig": {
          "SecurityGroupIds": [${env:Dev_SG1}],
          "SubnetIds": [
            "${env:Subnet_A}",
            "${env:Subnet_B}"
          ]

Comment: ERROR: Error parsing CloudFormation template: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Could you please help on this as I am unable to invoke gitlab variable values into serverless variable where I am expecting to replace variable with value from gitlab variable